# io_context.run() returns too early

Tags: api, c++11, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am making an api_client library based on boost-beast. I am using [composed operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html) to combine http::async_write() and http::async_read() into api_client::async_get().

The problem that I am facing is that io_context.run() function does now wait for http::async_read() to complete and return before the async_get() callback is called.

What am I doing wrong?
Any other suggestions to improve the code?

I am using boost 1.74 on Mac

```
// api_client.h

#ifndef API_CLIENT_H
#define API_CLIENT_H

#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace beast = boost::beast;          // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http  = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net   = boost::asio;           // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp       = boost::asio::ip::tcp;  // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

struct async_resolve_initiation
{
  template <typename CompletionHandler>
  void operator()(CompletionHandler &&completion_handler, tcp::resolver &resolver,
                  const std::string &host, const std::string &port) const
  {
    auto executor =
        boost::asio::get_associated_executor(completion_handler, resolver.get_executor());

    resolver.async_resolve(
        host, port,
        boost::asio::bind_executor(executor, std::forward<CompletionHandler>(completion_handler)));
  }
};

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_resolve_host(tcp::resolver &resolver, const std::string &host, const std::string &port,
                        CompletionToken &&token) ->
    typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
                                       void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                            const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>::return_type
{
  return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                                           const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>(
      async_resolve_initiation(), token, std::ref(resolver), host, port);
}

struct async_connect_initiation
{
  template <typename CompletionHandler>
  void operator()(CompletionHandler &&completion_handler, beast::tcp_stream &stream,
                  const tcp::resolver::results_type &results) const
  {

    stream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    auto executor = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(completion_handler, stream.get_executor());

    stream.async_connect(results, std::forward<CompletionHandler>(completion_handler));
  }
};

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_connect_host(beast::tcp_stream &stream, const tcp::resolver::results_type &results,
                        CompletionToken &&token) ->
    typename boost::asio::async_result<
        typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
        void(const boost::system::error_code &,
             const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>::return_type
{
  return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken,
                                     void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                          const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>(
      async_connect_initiation(), token, std::ref(stream), results);
}

struct async_request
{
  beast::tcp_stream &                              stream_;
  std::unique_ptr<http::request<http::empty_body>> req_;
  enum
  {
    request_in_progress,
    waiting_for_response,
  } state_;
  beast::flat_buffer                                 buffer_;
  std::shared_ptr<http::response<http::string_body>> res_;

  async_request(beast::tcp_stream &stream, std::unique_ptr<http::request<http::empty_body>> req)
    : stream_(stream)
    , req_(std::move(req))
    , state_(request_in_progress)
  {
    res_ = std::make_shared<http::response<http::string_body>>();
  }

  template <typename Self>
  void operator()(Self &self)
  {
    stream_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    http::async_write(stream_, *req_, std::move(self));
  }

  template <typename Self>
  void operator()(Self &self, const boost::system::error_code &error,
                  const std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      switch (state_)
      {
      case request_in_progress:
        http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, *res_, std::move(self));
        state_ = waiting_for_response;
        break;
      case waiting_for_response:
        self.complete(error);
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      self.complete(error);
    }
  }
};

struct api_client
{
  net::io_context & io_;
  beast::tcp_stream stream_;
  tcp::resolver     resolver_;
  const std::string base_url_;
  const std::string port_;

  api_client(net::io_context &io, const std::string &base_url, const std::string &port = "80")
    : io_(io)
    , stream_(net::make_strand(io))
    , resolver_(net::make_strand(io))
    , base_url_(base_url)
    , port_(port)
  {}

  template <typename CompletionToken>
  auto async_get(const std::string &path, CompletionToken &&token) ->
      typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
                                         void(const boost::system::error_code &)>::return_type
  {
    std::unique_ptr<http::request<http::empty_body>> req =
        std::make_unique<http::request<http::empty_body>>();

    req->version(11);
    req->method(http::verb::get);
    req->target(path);
    req->set(http::field::host, base_url_);

    return boost::asio::async_compose<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &)>(
        async_request(std::ref(stream_), std::move(req)), token);
  }

  template <typename CompletionToken>
  auto async_resolve_host(CompletionToken &&token) ->
      typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
                                         void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                              const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>::return_type
  {
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                                             const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>(
        async_resolve_initiation(), token, std::ref(resolver_), base_url_, port_);
  }

  template <typename CompletionToken>
  auto async_connect_host(const tcp::resolver::results_type &results, CompletionToken &&token) ->
      typename boost::asio::async_result<
          typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
          void(const boost::system::error_code &,
               const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>::return_type
  {
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken,
                                       void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                            const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>(
        async_connect_initiation(), token, std::ref(stream_), results);
  }
};

#endif
```

```
/// main.cpp

#include "api_client.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  net::io_context io_context;

  api_client client(io_context, "www.google.com");

  client.async_resolve_host(
      [&client](const boost::system::error_code &ec, const tcp::resolver::results_type &results) {
        if (!ec)
        {
          client.async_connect_host(
              results, [&client](const boost::system::error_code &                 ec,
                                 const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &endpoint) {
                if (!ec)
                {
                  std::cout << "connected at " << endpoint << std::endl;
                  client.async_get("/", [](const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
                    std::cout << "async_get: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                  });
                }
              });
        }
      });
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  io_context.run();  // PROBLEM: this function returns before callback of async_get() is called
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
project(main)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::system)
```

Comment: You could see this behaviour if async_connect_host or async_resolve_host return with a failure.

Comment: @janm Is this a comment or a question?

Comment: Kudos for the excellent sample. I learned a thing a two from reading it (I haven't "adopted" `async_compose` yet, so I'm behind the curve here :))

Comment: @goto It's a comment. You don't print a message on failure, so if there is a failure the process will complete because no new work is queued in the handler. I didn't bother reading through the rest of your code, but there is an answer that seems to cover the issues there.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks as though it DOES run on, but it crashes. Specifically, it prints (on my system in debug build):

```
connected at 216.58.214.4:80
async_get: buffer overflow
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### The Source Of UB

The issue appears to be that your `async_request` operation is a value-type and is moved (many times).

> Observe this by "instrumenting" manually:
>
> ```
> ~async_request() { std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
> async_request(async_request&&) = default;
> ```

Most members are move-enabled, but the `flat_buffer` simply doesn't exist anymore at the original address. This is also confirmed when you run with ASAN enabled:

```
connected at 216.58.208.100:80
=================================================================
==14000==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x615000000300 at pc 0x7fdc5aff11f9 bp 0x7fff92b42110 sp 0x7fff92b418b8
WRITE of size 512 at 0x615000000300 thread T0
    #0 0x7fdc5aff11f8  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x3b1f8)
    #1 0x7fdc5b02a5f4  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x745f4)
    #2 0x7fdc5b02acf3 in __interceptor_recvmsg (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x74cf3)
    #3 0x55d8dc9fcba4 in boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::recv(int, iovec*, unsigned long, int, boost::system::error_code&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:773
    #4 0x55d8dc9fcf73 in boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::non_blocking_recv(int, iovec*, unsigned long, int, bool, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:940
    #5 0x55d8dcbd2137 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op_base<boost::beast::buffers_prefix_view<boost::asio::mutable_buffer> >::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp:72
    #6 0x55d8dc9dd461 in boost::asio::detail::reactor_op::perform() /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/reactor_op.hpp:44
    #7 0x55d8dc9ee468 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::perform_io(unsigned int) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:743
    #8 0x55d8dc9ee829 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(void*, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:774
    #9 0x55d8dc9d711e in boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::complete(void*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/scheduler_operation.hpp:40
    #10 0x55d8dc9f748d in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:481
    #11 0x55d8dc9f46a4 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:204
    #12 0x55d8dc9fa2e1 in boost::asio::io_context::run() /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/impl/io_context.ipp:63
    #13 0x55d8dc9024ff in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:232
    #14 0x7fdc59871b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #15 0x55d8dc901929 in _start (/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/sotest+0x49e929)

0x615000000300 is located 0 bytes inside of 512-byte region [0x615000000300,0x615000000500)
freed by thread T0 here:
==14000==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_descriptions.cpp:177 "((res.trace)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    #0 0x7fdc5b06dba4  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xb7ba4)
    #1 0x7fdc5b08d1da  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xd71da)
    #2 0x7fdc5afe2adc  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x2cadc)
    #3 0x7fdc5afe483a  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x2e83a)
    #4 0x7fdc5afe7edb  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x31edb)
    #5 0x7fdc5b06d99b  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xb799b)
    #6 0x7fdc5b06d255  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xb7255)
    #7 0x7fdc5aff1221  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x3b221)
    #8 0x7fdc5b02a5f4  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x745f4)
    #9 0x7fdc5b02acf3 in __interceptor_recvmsg (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0x74cf3)
    #10 0x55d8dc9fcba4 in boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::recv(int, iovec*, unsigned long, int, boost::system::error_code&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:773
    #11 0x55d8dc9fcf73 in boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::non_blocking_recv(int, iovec*, unsigned long, int, bool, boost::system::error_code&, unsigned long&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:940
    #12 0x55d8dcbd2137 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op_base<boost::beast::buffers_prefix_view<boost::asio::mutable_buffer> >::do_perform(boost::asio::detail::reactor_op*) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_recv_op.hpp:72
    #13 0x55d8dc9dd461 in boost::asio::detail::reactor_op::perform() /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/reactor_op.hpp:44
    #14 0x55d8dc9ee468 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::perform_io(unsigned int) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:743
    #15 0x55d8dc9ee829 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::descriptor_state::do_complete(void*, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:774
    #16 0x55d8dc9d711e in boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation::complete(void*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/scheduler_operation.hpp:40
    #17 0x55d8dc9f748d in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:481
    #18 0x55d8dc9f46a4 in boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run(boost::system::error_code&) /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:204
    #19 0x55d8dc9fa2e1 in boost::asio::io_context::run() /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_74_0/boost/asio/impl/io_context.ipp:63
    #20 0x55d8dc9024ff in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:232
    #21 0x7fdc59871b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #22 0x55d8dc901929 in _start (/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/sotest+0x49e929)
```

The "cheap" way to work around it would be to add another smart pointer. However:

- this adds more dynamic allocations/implementation fragmentation
- `enable_shared_from_this` seems to become more to the pooint
- IIRC Beast has an abstraction for this (look for `handler_ptr` or similar?). My goto resource for this are

  - the Beast documentation (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html)
  - This evergreen post by Vinnie Falco https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6aygos/boostasio_asynchronous_composed_operation_tutorial/

### Another Subtle Issue

There is another issue lurking after fixing the above:

```
http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, *res_, std::move(self));
state_ = waiting_for_response;
```

You update the `state_` AFTER moving. That's use-after-move. That's not UB here because it's a primitive type member. But it's also not what you wanted. Reorder that:

```
state_ = waiting_for_response;
http::async_read(stream_, *buffer_, *res_, std::move(self));
```

### Minimal Fixed Version:

**Live On Coliru**

```
// api_client.h
#ifndef API_CLIENT_H
#define API_CLIENT_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace beast = boost::beast;          // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http  = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net   = boost::asio;           // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp       = boost::asio::ip::tcp;  // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

struct async_resolve_initiation
{
  template <typename CompletionHandler>
  void operator()(CompletionHandler &&completion_handler, tcp::resolver &resolver,
                  const std::string &host, const std::string &port) const
  {
    auto executor =
        boost::asio::get_associated_executor(completion_handler, resolver.get_executor());

    resolver.async_resolve(
        host, port,
        boost::asio::bind_executor(executor, std::forward<CompletionHandler>(completion_handler)));
  }
};

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_resolve_host(tcp::resolver &resolver, const std::string &host, const std::string &port,
                        CompletionToken &&token) ->
    typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
                                       void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                            const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>::return_type
{
  return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                                           const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>(
      async_resolve_initiation(), token, std::ref(resolver), host, port);
}

struct async_connect_initiation
{
  template <typename CompletionHandler>
  void operator()(CompletionHandler &&completion_handler, beast::tcp_stream &stream,
                  const tcp::resolver::results_type &results) const
  {

    stream.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    auto executor = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(completion_handler, stream.get_executor());

    stream.async_connect(results, std::forward<CompletionHandler>(completion_handler));
  }
};

template <typename CompletionToken>
auto async_connect_host(beast::tcp_stream &stream, const tcp::resolver::results_type &results,
                        CompletionToken &&token) ->
    typename boost::asio::async_result<
        typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
        void(const boost::system::error_code &,
             const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>::return_type
{
  return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken,
                                     void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                          const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>(
      async_connect_initiation(), token, std::ref(stream), results);
}

struct async_request
{
  beast::tcp_stream &                              stream_;
  std::unique_ptr<http::request<http::empty_body>> req_;
  enum
  {
    request_in_progress,
    waiting_for_response,
  } state_;
  std::unique_ptr<beast::flat_buffer>                buffer_;
  std::shared_ptr<http::response<http::string_body>> res_;

  async_request(beast::tcp_stream &stream, std::unique_ptr<http::request<http::empty_body>> req)
    : stream_(stream)
    , req_(std::move(req))
    , state_(request_in_progress)
  {
    res_ = std::make_shared<http::response<http::string_body>>();
    buffer_ = std::make_unique<boost::beast::flat_buffer>();
  }

  template <typename Self>
  void operator()(Self &self)
  {
    stream_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
    http::async_write(stream_, *req_, std::move(self));
  }

  template <typename Self>
  void operator()(Self &self, const boost::system::error_code &error,
                  const std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      switch (state_)
      {
      case request_in_progress:
        state_ = waiting_for_response;
        http::async_read(stream_, *buffer_, *res_, std::move(self));
        break;
      case waiting_for_response:
        self.complete(error);
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      self.complete(error);
    }
  }
};

struct api_client
{
  net::io_context & io_;
  beast::tcp_stream stream_;
  tcp::resolver     resolver_;
  const std::string base_url_;
  const std::string port_;

  api_client(net::io_context &io, std::string base_url, std::string port = "80")
    : io_(io)
    , stream_(net::make_strand(io))
    , resolver_(net::make_strand(io))
    , base_url_(std::move(base_url))
    , port_(std::move(port))
  {}

  template <typename CompletionToken>
  auto async_get(const std::string &path, CompletionToken &&token) ->
      typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
                                         void(const boost::system::error_code &)>::return_type
  {
    std::unique_ptr<http::request<http::empty_body>> req =
        std::make_unique<http::request<http::empty_body>>();

    req->version(11);
    req->method(http::verb::get);
    req->target(path);
    req->set(http::field::host, base_url_);

    return boost::asio::async_compose<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &)>(
        async_request(std::ref(stream_), std::move(req)), token);
  }

  template <typename CompletionToken>
  auto async_resolve_host(CompletionToken &&token) ->
      typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
                                         void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                              const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>::return_type
  {
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                                             const tcp::resolver::results_type &)>(
        async_resolve_initiation(), token, std::ref(resolver_), base_url_, port_);
  }

  template <typename CompletionToken>
  auto async_connect_host(const tcp::resolver::results_type &results, CompletionToken &&token) ->
      typename boost::asio::async_result<
          typename std::decay<CompletionToken>::type,
          void(const boost::system::error_code &,
               const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>::return_type
  {
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken,
                                       void(const boost::system::error_code &,
                                            const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &)>(
        async_connect_initiation(), token, std::ref(stream_), results);
  }
};

#endif

/// main.cpp

//#include "api_client.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  net::io_context io_context;

  api_client client(io_context, "www.google.com");

  client.async_resolve_host(
      [&client](const boost::system::error_code &ec, const tcp::resolver::results_type &results) {
        //std::cout << "resolved " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        if (!ec)
        {
          client.async_connect_host(
              results, [&client](const boost::system::error_code &                 ec,
                                 const tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &endpoint) {
                if (!ec)
                {
                  std::cout << "connected at " << endpoint << std::endl;
                  client.async_get("/", [](const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
                    std::cout << "async_get: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                  });
                }
              });
        }
      });

  io_context.run();
}
```

Prints:

```
connected at 216.58.208.100:80
async_get: Success
```

Comment: In "random" note, consider using `asio::async_connect` to do the composed resolve/connect dance.

Comment: Thanks for a working version. I am using boost 1.74 on mac, so that explains the different behavior. I believe the real problem is pass some additional executors like this 

boost::asio::async_compose<CompletionToken, void(const boost::system::error_code &)>(
        async_request(std::ref(stream_), std::move(req)), token, stream_, io_);

Comment: Caution! [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#:~:text=In%20the%20C%20community,%20undefined%20behavior%20may%20be%20humorously%20referred%20to%20as%20) is a curse: it can do everything. So even though "that explains the different behavior" it doesn't mean the UB isn't a serious problem.

Comment: And yes, I didn't see a secondary executor passed around but that can indeed lead to the problem described: any operation is exercising an executor work-guard for the duration of the operation. However, if the secondary executor is not dependent on the main executor (from your original execution context) then it will fail to keep it "busy".

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to use enable_shared_from_this with composed operations?